# PRFilledPolygon - Opacity/Color with Cocos2d in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

i have a question about `PRFilledPolygon` from `PrKit` which you can found [here](http://github.com/Panajev/PRKit/blob/master-v2/PRKit/PRFilledPolygon.m)

My concern is to `runAction` with `CCFadeout` or `CCFadein` with this class.

This class inherits from `CCNode` which have no methods like `setColor` or `setOpacity`. But to run this actions which i named above require a methode `setOpacity` to make the texture transparent.

So my first step was to in change "`CCNode`" to "`CCNodeRGBA`". I have no idea what my next step is. I have read out in other forums and found this [article](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/prfilledpolygon-opacitycolor/)

But this doesn't work.

second found article [here](http://insights.empatika.com/blog/2013/04/06/hackathon-ios-game-in-7-days/)

So i play a bit in the draw method but my texture won't be transparent.

Has anybody used `PRFilledPolygon` and has the same problem like me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution: modify [prfilledpolygon class with opacity and color](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/2ZIUM1BIAE)

Thanks to joshuawilde from cocos2d forum.